# Is it possible to apply an iptables rule only for internal ips?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, nat

Currently, I have a NAT instance in AWS with some iptables rules, such as to forward the traffic that comes in a certain port to some other instance. So, if I do `curl nat.address.com:8090`, the traffic is forwarded to some other instance that is listening to the 8090 port, let's say it is instance A.

What I want is to know how to apply this rule only if the original source is inside the local network. That is, if the request to `nat.address.com:8090`comes from an internal instance with ip `172.31.10.10`, the nat instance should forward it to instance A. However, if the request to `nat.address.com:8090` comes from some external source (e.g. `189.58.200.10`), it should not forward.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should by able to use -s option. Can you post your iptables table?

Comment: Yes, a bit after I posted this question I thought about the `-s` option. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) you can use the -s option:

```
-s, --source [!] address[/mask]
Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname (please note that specifying any name to be resolved with a remote query such as DNS is a really bad idea), a network IP address (with /mask), or a plain IP address. The mask can be either a network mask or a plain number, specifying the number of 1's at the left side of the network mask. Thus, a mask of 24 is equivalent to 255.255.255.0. A "!" argument before the address specification inverts the sense of the address. The flag --src is an alias for this option.
```

For example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.10.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of two ways:

**(1) Security Group rules:**

You can add appropriate rules in the Security Group(s) which is associated with your NAT instance. This will block inbound flow of all packets on port 8090 that are originating from any source which is not your internal instance.

For ex: If you would like to forward packets which are originating from a particular instance with IP 172.31.10.10, you would add an inbound rule in the Security Group of your NAT instance which would look like:

```
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 8090
Source: 172.31.10.10
```

And you have to make sure that there are no other rules inside the Security Group which would allow traffic on TCP port 8090 from any other source.

And if you would like to make sure that your NAT instance forwards traffic from all the internal instances inside your VPC, then you can edit the Source field to include the CIDR range of your VPC.

This option would be suitable only if you are aware of the network traffic that hits your NAT instance so that you can appropriately add the rules inside your Security Group to match your incoming traffic, otherwise you will end up blocking the meaningful traffic as well.

**(2) IPTable rules:**

This option requires you to add IPTable rules on your NAT instance such that your NAT instance will only accept network traffic from a specific network (which is your VPC) and only from a specific TCP port. For ex, if you would like to make sure your NAT instance only accepts traffic from your internal instances (i.e. instances inside your VPC) on port 8090, then the following rules would apply:

- $ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 172.31.0.0/16 --dport 8090 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
- $ iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 8090 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT